# Extend existing interface with mongoose document

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I have an interface

```
export interface ICategory {
    name: string,
    subCats: Array<Schema.Types.ObjectId>,
    thumbnail: string
}
```

I want to extend this `ICategory` with mongoose's `Document`

I've tried like this

```
export interface ICategoryDocument extends Document<ICategory> {}
```

then I've used it in schema with `model<T>()` but its showing

```
No overload matches this call
Type 'Model<any>' is not assignable to type 'ICategoryModel'.
```

Here's my total code.

**Salon.types.ts**

```
import { Document, Model, Schema, SchemaDefinition } from 'mongoose'
import { ParamsDictionary } from 'express-serve-static-core'

namespace Salon {
    export interface ICategory {
        name: string,
        subCats: Array<Schema.Types.ObjectId>,
        thumbnail: string
    }
    export interface ICategoryDefinition extends ICategory, SchemaDefinition {}
    export interface ICategoryDocument extends Document<ICategory> {}
    export interface ICategoryModel extends ICategory, Model<ICategoryDocument> {
        lol: string
    }
    export interface ICategoryParam extends ParamsDictionary {
        categoryId: string
    }
}

export default Salon
```

**Salon.schema.ts**

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'
import Salon from '../../types/salon'

const CategorySchema = new Schema<Salon.ICategoryDocument, Salon.ICategoryModel, Salon.ICategoryDefinition>({
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    subCats: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, default: [], ref: 'Service' }],
    thumbnail: { type: String, required: false }
})

const CategoryModel = model<Salon.ICategoryDocument>('Category', CategorySchema, 'categories')

export default CategoryModel
```

on this line

```
const CategoryModel = model<Salon.ICategoryDocument>('Category', CategorySchema, 'categories')
```

```
error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(name: string, schema?: Schema<Document<any>, Model<Document<any>>, undefined> | undefined, collection?: string | undefined, skipInit?: boolean | undefined): Model<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Schema<ICategoryDocument, ICategoryModel, ICategoryDefinition>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Schema<Document<any>, Model<Document<any>>, undefined>'.
      Types of property 'statics' are incompatible.
        Type '{ [name: string]: (this: ICategoryModel, ...args: any[]) => any; }' is not assignable to type '{ [name: string]: (this: Model<Document<any>>, ...args: any[]) => any; }'.
          Index signatures are incompatible.
            Type '(this: ICategoryModel, ...args: any[]) => any' is not assignable to type '(this: Model<Document<any>>, ...args: any[]) => any'.
              The 'this' types of each signature are incompatible.
                Type 'Model<Document<any>>' is not assignable to type 'ICategoryModel'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(name: string, schema?: Schema<any, Model<any>, undefined> | undefined, collection?: string | undefined, skipInit?: boolean | undefined): Model<ICategoryDocument>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Schema<ICategoryDocument, ICategoryModel, ICategoryDefinition>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Schema<any, Model<any>, undefined>'.
      Types of property 'statics' are incompatible.
        Type '{ [name: string]: (this: ICategoryModel, ...args: any[]) => any; }' is not assignable to type '{ [name: string]: (this: Model<any>, ...args: any[]) => any; }'.
          Index signatures are incompatible.
            Type '(this: ICategoryModel, ...args: any[]) => any' is not assignable to type '(this: Model<any>, ...args: any[]) => any'.
              The 'this' types of each signature are incompatible.
                Type 'Model<any>' is not assignable to type 'ICategoryModel'.

10 const CategoryModel = model<Salon.ICategoryDocument>('Category', CategorySchema, 'categories')
                                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


src/routes/salon/category.ts:16:51 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Condition<ICategory | undefined>'.

16         const category = await Category.findOne({ _id: categoryId })
                                                     ~~~


Found 2 errors.
```

Comment: Try to avoid using `namespace`